# Удаление каждого 3 элемента массива

Tags: php, массивы, notepad++

Здравствуйте.
Есть файл, содержащий в себе массивы данных, пример:

```
$arr['firstGroup'] = array(
array('firstname', 'lastname', 'city', 'country'),
.......
);
$arr['secondGroup'] = array(
array('firstname', 'lastname', 'city', 'country'),
.......
);
```

Необходимо удалить каждый 3 элемент массива, в данном случае 'city'
И на выходе получить готовый код с массивом, не включающим в себя элемент city, т.е. 'firstname', 'lastname', 'country'
Так как вручную удалять это сложно и долго (60000 строк), то хотел бы поинтересоваться есть ли автоматизированный метод.

Comment: `for` + `array_splice`

Comment: и вывести массив с помощью echo?
Ибо мне нужен сам код массива, так как это своего рода база данных статических данных

Comment: Можете echo, можете скриптом сгенерировать файл с готовым исправленным php

Comment: @Ilya78rus: там третий элемент видимо не только "city" может быть?

Comment: city это условное обозначение для примера подобрал
А так там разное значение может быть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ещё актуально:

```
<?php

$arr['firstGroup'] = array(
    array('firstname', 'lastname', 'city', 'country'),
);

$arr['secondGroup'] = array(
    array('firstname', 'lastname', 'city', 'country')
);

for (reset($arr); ($k = key($arr)); next($arr)) {
    for ($i = 0, $j = count($arr[$k]); $i < $j; $i++) {
        array_splice($arr[$k][$i], 2, 1);
    }
}

echo '<pre>'; var_dump($arr); echo '</pre>';

/*

array(2) {
  ["firstGroup"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "firstname"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "lastname"
      [2]=>
      string(7) "country"
    }
  }
  ["secondGroup"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "firstname"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "lastname"
      [2]=>
      string(7) "country"
    }
  }
}

*/
```

Comment: @Ilya78rus а если уже не нужно решение, я его удалю.